# Why not Hierarchy theory rather than ZFC be the foundation of sets and mathematics?

Tags: set-theory, foundations, philosophy

***Hierarchy theory*** is the theory obtained by adding a one place function $V$ to the first order language of set theory.

*Define* $``ordinal"$ along Von Neumann's, also $``<"$ is defined in the usual manner over von Neumann ordinals only.

Add axioms of: **Extensionality; Separation**, stipulated in the usual manner.

**Stages:** $\forall \ ordinal \ \alpha: V_\alpha = \{x \subseteq V_\beta | \beta < \alpha\}$

**Foundation:** $\forall x \exists \ ordinal \ \alpha \  ( x \in V_\alpha    )$

**Infinity:** $\exists \alpha [\alpha \neq \emptyset \land \forall \beta < \alpha \exists \gamma (\beta < \gamma < \alpha)]$

**Height:** $\forall x [x \text{ is well ordered } \to \exists  \ ordinal \ \alpha: \alpha= ord(x)] $

Where $ord(x)$ means the order type of $x$.

/ Theory definition finished.

I think the above axioms are the ones that truly capture the notion of an infinite hierarchy of sets that is built from below, the last axiom [to me] makes full sense and it does belong to the notion of a hierarchy itself, since it reflects the build up from below notion, i.e. we can add up heights to the hierarchy as long as those are formed at earlier stages!

Now of course we can add up further ordinal lengths like: fixed points, inaccessible, Mahlo, etc.. and thereby obtain higher hierarchies.  On the other hand we can thin up stages by adding axioms stating that all sets are well ordered, or that all of them are constructible, thereby filtering out any discourse about non-well ordered sets, or about non-constructible sets.

However those additions of lengths to the hierarchy and those thinnings of its stages, I don't see any of them really stemming from the very basic notion of *hierarchy* itself, they can be conceived as manipulations on that notion rather than stemming essentially from it. However these manipulations seem to preserve the notion of a hierarchy, and so can be seen as constituting different *versions* of it.

So for example $\sf ZFC$ can be seen as a special case of a hierarchy, namely when the hierarchy has inaccessible height and thinned out to have only well ordered sets.

So the overall notion of a hierarchy with various lengthening and\or thinning of it, is a bigger notion than the axioms of $\sf ZFC$, and it *is* the foundational notion about sets and mathematics thereof. And I see the above theory being the basic form of it, not $\sf ZFC$ which only captures a special manipulation of its height and width.

> What mathematical and foundational arguments can be held against this position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems.

Some mathematical: e.g. every real is a subset of $\omega$ and thus can be well-ordered, but if the reals cannot be well-ordered, you just said you can omit them, so in particular you won't have a von Neumann hierarchy for more than $\omega+1$ steps.

Others linguistic, who said that ZFC is **the** foundational theory? It's a popular one, yes, but there are others, and most mathematicians are not particularly picky about their foundations anyway.

Finally, philosophical. We know that ZFC is far stronger than "bare necessity" in most of mathematics. It's nothing new that Replacement, in some sense, is not needed for foundations. Replacement has its set theoretic merits (Reflection, for example) and a few foundational merits (implementation insensitivity which means it doesn't matter how you encode structures into set theory). But as a whole, it is not necessary for most of mathematics.

You seem to keep some of the consequences of Replacement (most notably the von Neumann hierarchy, and "enough ordinals"), but not all. Your theory is already "too strong" for most of mathematics, and it is not strong enough for set theoretic research, where Reflection plays a key role.

So what should we do with this theory? Yes, it's cute, it's interesting to ask what things it *can't* do, but ultimately, if you're interested in foundations for foundational sake, ditch Replacement altogether, and any Separation beyond $\Delta_0$ is unnecessary either. If you're really pressing it, kill power set and preserve, maybe, the power set of $\omega$, or go "full Pocket" and treat uncountable sets as classes.

But ultimately the question on "the foundation" is sociological. To quote a prominent mathematician replying to my question about AC when I was starting my M.Sc. studies, a good foundational theory is one that you don't notice when you do mathematics. If your foundations interferes with your mathematics, it's not the best foundations you can find. (Note, an inconsistent foundations *does* interfere with your mathematics, proving that $0=1$ is quite disruptive to mathematics.)

Comment: I didn't get your argument about not being able to go beyond $\omega + 1$ steps? I thought this theory goes up (without including) to the first fixed point on the omega function.

Comment: Yes, but if the reals cannot be well ordered, and you only take well ordered objects, then you no longer have $V_{\omega+1}$.

Comment: even if the reals are not well ordered, there still would be sets that are well ordered of order type $\omega + \omega$, and actually of any countable order type. So the hierarchy won't stop at $\omega+1$ anyway.

Comment: You are not reading what I'm saying. You wrote that you can remove all sets which are non-well ordered and "thereby getting choice". I am saying that this is not quite the case. I did not say that there are no infinite ordinals. I said that the von Neumann hierarchy cannot exist (if $\Bbb R$ cannot be well-ordered).

Comment: Possibly there is an error somewhere I'm not sure, and possibly its on my side, especially my expression might be wrong, but let me explicate what I meant "by removal of all non-well ordered sets" I actually mean if we add an axiom that states that "all sets are well orderable", that's what I meant. I thought that this addition will enact choice.  Now even if choice is not there (I mean we permit non-well ordered sets, i.e. don't add the well ordering axiom) still we'll have more than $\omega+1$ stages anyway because there are countable ordinals higher than it and those would have stages!

Comment: You wrote, and I quote, "filtering out special kinds of sets like taking out all non well ordered sets (thereby getting choice)", you literally talk about thinning out the sets. You're not adding axioms, you're hoping to get axioms by removing sets. Sometimes this works, e.g. in the case of constructibility, but usually it's more subtle than "remove witnesses to failure of choice".

Comment: If $\Bbb R$ is not well-orderable, and you only allow sets that can be well-ordered, then $V_{\omega+1}$ is not one of these sets. Period. We can move on now.

Comment: I see now what you mean, but honestly its not what I meant. I don't mean that we can have a version of the theory in which there are non-well ordered sets, and then make a definitional restriction to get rid of those and that the defined structure would satisfy being a hierarchy with choice. I admit that my phrasing of it might give this impression but that's not what I meant. What I meant by getting rid of non-well orderable sets, is to add an axiom that all sets are well orderable to the above theory and thus filter out any possible discourse about existence of such sets in that version.

Comment: Well, that's all nice, and I guess this is what you had meant. The real issue, of course, the philosophical one.

Comment: OK, I saw your last comment now. I'll re-phrase it to make sure it doesn't give this impression. Thanks of course for telling me about it.

Comment: There is something deeper in what I'm saying! Notice that I've alluded to something more than just this theory, that is to the display of "whole" foundational *record* (i.e. all the lengthenings and the thinnings of this theory), to me ZFC corresponds to a sub-record of that record, where the theories on that record are all of inaccessible height (that's how I view the ZFC based hierarchical record (i.e. extensions of ZFC and thinnings of ZFC)). To me I don't see why should one abide by this sub-record? I see the full hierarchical record as the right one, and this theory is its heart (not ZFC)

Comment: It appears that reflection is the main point here. Although I don't see how to trace this in the basic notion of a hierarchy, yet no doubt its a powerful tool that demands attention.